# java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 98 with Akka

Tags: scala, heroku, akka

After Heroku change the default version of OpenJDK, the backend have problems when I try to deploy, the stack are: Playframework, Akka 2.3.4 and Scala. When I try to deploy the backend, Heroku show this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 98
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can revert to the older JDK by putting the following in a `system.properties` file:

```
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_102
```

Add that file to Git and redeploy.